# Dependent MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, dependencies, greatest-n-per-group

My problem is the following:

My tables are `MESSAGE` and `MESSAGE_COMMENT`,

```
MESSAGE (id,content)

MESSAGE_COMMENT (id, message_id, content)
```

I need to select all messages and ***max 3 comments*** for each message, like in this example:

```
type | id | content
M      15   "this is a message with no comments"
M      16   "this is another message with many comments"
R      16   "comment1"
R      16   "comment2"
R      16   "comment3"
M      17   "this is another message with no comments"
```

"id" is `MESSAGE.id` when it's a message and `COMMENT.message_id` when it's a comment.

I hope I have clearly explained my problem..

Comment: Can the comments be in any order or should they be ordered by id?

Comment: Do you really need your query to include values from different tables/columns in the 'content' field like this? If you had different columns in your returned data for message content and comment content, you'd be able to write a simpler SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  m.id,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  id
                FROM    message_comment mc
                WHERE   mc.message_id = m.id
                ORDER BY
                        mc.message_id DESC, id DESC
                LIMIT 2, 1
                ), 0) AS mid
        FROM    message m
        ) mo
LEFT JOIN
        message_comment mcd
ON      mcd.message_id >= mo.id
        AND mcd.message_id <= mo.id
        AND mcd.id >= mid
```

Create an index on `message_comment (message_id, id)` for this to work fast.

See this article in my blog for more detailed explanation of how this works:

- [**Advanced row sampling**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/06/advanced-row-sampling/)

Comment: thank you for your answer.
i've tried the query but it doesn't display the messages without comment.. how can i solve this?

Comment: @unknown (yahoo): replace the `JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`. I've updated the query.

Comment: @Riedsio: don't worry, it's not too complex for MySQL's parser.

Answer (score 0):

That's all because PHP is parsed in your server (side) and the HTML generated by it go to client browser and get renderized...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of unions, but sometimes they have their places... :)

```
SELECT type, id, content FROM ( 
SELECT 'M' AS type, id, 0 AS reply_id, content FROM MESSAGE
UNION
SELECT 'R' AS type, message_id AS id, id AS reply_id, content FROM MESSAGE_COMMENT) a 
ORDER BY id, reply_id
```

returns

```
+------+----+--------------------------------------------+
| type | id | content                                    |
+------+----+--------------------------------------------+
| M    | 15 | this is a message with no comments         |
| M    | 16 | this is another message with many comments |
| R    | 16 | comment1                                   |
| R    | 16 | comment2                                   |
| R    | 16 | comment3                                   |
| M    | 17 | this is another message with no comments   |
+------+----+--------------------------------------------+
```

NB: The second `SELECT` in the `UNION` could easily be reworked with an `INNER JOIN` to the `MESSAGE` table if orphaned message_comments were a concern.